# Accessing User Attributes from Uploader with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to set a default pic using carrierwave, but want to set it based on a specific user attribute.

```
def default_url
  if user.attribute == "Foo"
    "foo.png'
  else
    "default.png"
end
```

However, doing this throws an error.

```
NameError in Users#index
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<ImageUrlUploader:0x43f4b80>
```

Is there any way to allow the uploader to access the user?

Comment: Can u update your question with error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the uploader class you have access to the mounted object through `model`. If your object has a relation with `User` you could retrieve the user from this.